# How to fix a damaged MKV video file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, matroska

I have a damaged MKV file (power turned off while recording).
I know how to get the actual video duration (e.g. decode and send output to null, take the last frame reported PTS).

How do I edit the container and stream duration, so that it will appear correct?

Comment: You can just remux.

Comment: @Gyan cmdline plz

Comment: `ffmpeg -i recorded.mkv -map 0 -c copy new.mkv`

Comment: @Gyan already tried it and it doesnt work

Comment: Remux to MPEG-TS first and then mux to MKV. Else share full log of your attempt.